# TCL expect regular expression

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I am trying to write one script which climbs up from one system to another through TCL/Expect. It is working for me. I need a regular expression in which **expect "$ "** and **expect "# "** is combined , so that any system with any **prompt** in the path can be included.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# Using ssh from expect

log_user 0
spawn ssh test@192.168.2.24
expect "sword: "
send "test\r"
expect "$ "
send "ssh beta\r"
expect "# "
send "uptime\r"
expect "# "

set igot $expect_out(buffer)
puts $igot
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this:

```
expect -re {[$#] }
```

The keys to this are: add the `-re` flag so that we can match an RE, and put the RE in `{braces}` so that it doesn't get substituted.

Answer (score 8):

A more generic solution:

```
set prompt "(%|#|\\\$) $"
expect -re $prompt
```

This one matches **%**, **#** and **$**.
The second dollar sign ensures matching the pattern only at the end of input.